# Как открыть файл java

Tags: java, android, файлы

Есть путь к определеному файлу (`storage/sdcard/file.txt`).
Нужно этот файл открыть, прочесть, и данные, которые находятся в нем, поместить в `String` строку.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Сохраняем директорию SD-карты в файл
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

// Берём текстовый файл из корня SD-карты
// В этой переменной будет храниться наш файл
File file = new File(sdcard, "file.txt");

// Читаем текст из файла
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
    br.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // Обрабатываем ошибки
}

// Теперь в переменной 'text' будет храниться весь текст из файла
```

Оригинал: [How can I read a text file from the SD card in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902689/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-sd-card-in-android)

Также стоит не забывать, что для чтения/записи на SD-карту потребуется прописать нужные строчки в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

И, как подметили в комментариях, стоит также позаботиться о нужных правах доступа во время выполнения приложение (а не до установки) — подробнее можно почитать, например, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549561/how-to-check-grants-permissions-at-run-time).

Comment: Также может потребоваться выданное юзером в рантайме разрешение на чтение с диска, если ОС версии > 6

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, я добавил про разрешения :)

Comment: Я имел в виду не только это) На 6+ ОС эти разрешения в манифесте недостаточно прописать) Надо ещё и в рантайме проверить, что они есть и запросить, если нет)